# Facebook app graph api feed returning empty data set

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

Previously working data feed from FB app https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN has stopped working. 
Response is now an empty data set: 
{
   "data": [

]
}
Nothing has changed since on the part of the app.
There were at least 50 posts in the app wall before this happened.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would really help to see your code.

Comment: simple api call from above returns an empty data set. tnx.

Comment: the code hasn't been changed since, also. this call is used to fetch JSON data and display it in the web page.

Answer (score 0):

> There were at least 50 posts in the app wall before this happened.

There is no such thing as an “app wall” any more – per se.

To have a page for an app, you nowadays have to create one especially – apps do not have corresponding pages automatically any more.

There has been a transition period, where you could turn an old app page into a “normal” page and link your app with that – but I don’t think that’s possible any more.

So, do you have a page that is linked to your app? (What is the ID of your app, so that we can check it out ourself on the API?)